# Connecting to Amazon AWS TimeOut Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to connect to a Redshift instance. If I use psycopg2 to test the connection and grab a simple query, I get a:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Operation timed ouT
>
> Is the server running on host "THE_HOST" (10.0.21.77) and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I have no idea how to diagnose this. My router is set to 192.168.0.1 rather than the 10.0.0.1 config. I'm not sure what I need to pass to make this happen...

Edits: I'm connecting through a VPN. I know the redshift cluster accepts incoming connections over this VPN. I can also connect to the cluster through pgAdminIII or SQLWorkbench

Comment: Check your security groups, whether your router's public IP address has access to the RedShift cluster.

Comment: You're trying to connect to your Redshift cluster via its private IP from your local machine? This can't work: use the public IP, make sure it is publicly exposed (check the cluster settings) and confirm that the cluster security groups allow your IP.

Comment: Also check if the port 5432 is in the inbound ports of the security groups

Comment: @Nicolas I' connecting through a VPN.